# SED change second occurence in all lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace, text-files

The normal expression to change `server1` to `server1-bck` is

```
sed -i 's/server1/server1-bck/g' file.out
```

so all `server1` will be changed to `server1-bck`.  What I need is to change the second occurence of the expression in every line.

For example,
before text:

```
rename files tsm_node1 //server1/document/users/  //server1/document/users/
```

desired after text:

```
rename files tsm_node1 //server1/document/users/  //server1-bck/document/users/
```

How can I do that?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -i 's/server1/&-bck/2' file.out`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "rename files tsm_node1 //server1/document/users/ //server1/document/users/" |\
sed  's/server1/server1-bck/2g'
```

`sed`'s famous substitution works like this:
`sed 's/regex/replacement/flags'`

Flags could be a number, in your case 2 for advising `sed` to execute this command on 2nd occurrence and if you need more, therefore the `g` flag is. If you are sure, there are no more items to be substituted, you can leave and forget the `g` flag.

If you don't pipe and have a file, do this:

`sed -i 's/server1/server1-bck/2g' file.out`.

Additionally you can replace parts of your regex pattern with `sed`'s `&` replacement if you want to substitute with that what you have found and will have:

`sed -i 's/server1/&-bck/2g' file.out`.

Comment: thanks a lot very helpfull,  I will do that on a existing file

Comment: @frodo You are welcome. If you think this answer is right and helpfull, please mark this answer as a right one. This will help the community finding right answers.